# How do I write the pattern matching correctly here?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

The following code works:

```
data MyList a = Atom a | Cons a (MyList a) deriving (Show)

getAtom (Atom a) = a

myFindMax :: (Ord a) => MyList a -> a 
myFindMax (Cons x xs) = let restMax = myFindMax xs in
                          if x > restMax then x else restMax
myFindMax x = getAtom x
```

But when I write

```
myFindMax (Atom x) = getAtom x
```

Before the other pattern, I get the error

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘MyList a’ with actual type ‘a’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for myFindMax :: Ord a => MyList a -> a
          at myList.hs:5:14
```

Why is the Atom case different from the Cons case?

Comment: btw. the `MyList` you are defining is not equivalent to the usual list, in this case you are defining a non-empty list! if you are interested and want to compare your solutions to something quite similar https://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroups-0.8.5/docs/Data-List-NonEmpty.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not different, it’s because there is an error:

```
myFindMax (Atom x) = getAtom x
```

will try to call `getAtom` to a value that is not (generally) an `Atom` value. The pattern is already doing the job of the `getAtom` function. You should write:

```
myFindMax (Atom x) = x
```